# Click and drag on trackpad doesn't move after reaching edges of trackpad

Tags: mouse, touchpad, drag-and-drop

There is a feature in Windows which helps in dragging when you reach the end of the touchpad. Like if you are dragging a folder in Ubuntu if you reach the edge of the touchpad the dragging just stops, whereas in Windows it continues to move on its own even after reaching the edge of the touchpad.

I was wondering whether there was a similar feature or a third-party app for Ubuntu that does this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no similar feature a.f.a.i.k. When your finger reached the edge of the touchpad, hold, place another finger (other hand will be easiest) and continue dragging with that other finger.